# Necessary condition for switching the order of limit and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

I am stuck on a remark in my lecture notes concerning switching the order of differentiation and limits of a sequence of functions. The below proof uses the fact that, under the condition that the convergence is uniform, the limit of $\int_a^x f_n(t) d t$ equals $\int_a^x f(t) d t$ and that a sequence of continuous functions converge to a continuous function.

> **Theorem.** Let $\left(f_n\right)_1^{\infty}$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable functions in the interval $E$. Assume that the sequence is pointwise convergent to the function $f$ and that the differentiated sequence $\left(f_n^{\prime}\right)_1^{\infty}$ is uniformly convergent to the function $g$ in $E$. Then $f$ is continuously differentiable in $E$ and $f^{\prime}=g$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $a$ be a point in $E$. We have that
> $$
> \int_a^x f_n^{\prime}(t) d t=f_n(x)-f_n(a), \quad x \in E,
> $$
> for $n=1,2, \ldots$. Now, letting $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get
> $$
> \int_a^x g(t) d t=f(x)-f(a), \quad x \in E .
> $$
> $g$ is continuous [since $\left(f_n^{\prime}\right)_1^{\infty}$ converges uniformly] and it follows from this that the function $f$ is differentiable in $E$ with $f^{\prime}(x)=g(x)$.
>
> **Remark.** In the proof, the uniform convergence is used only in the interval $[a,x]$. This implies that the conclusion of the theorem is true also under the following weakend assumption: For each $x\in E$, there is an open interval $E_x\ni x$ such that $\left(f_n^{\prime}\right)_1^{\infty}$ is uniformly convergent in $E_x$.

The "open interval" in the remark confuses me. I have tried rewriting the proof with this assumption, but I do not know how it would start. Something like:

> Let $a\in E$. Then there is an open interval $E_a$. Now how is this useful?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Continuity is a local property, hence you only need to prove the local uniform convergence, i.e. in a neighborhood. But maybe you forgot the assumption $E$ is open?

Comment: This just means that correctness of theorem on $[a,x]$ implies it's correctnes on $[a,x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Unfortunately the notes are a bit unclear what $E$ is, if it's open or not. Continuity is indeed a local property, but the author is specifically writing that we only used the uniform convergence for the interval $[a,x]$, i.e. we didn't use it on any open interval.

Comment: Never mind my question actually, I think I have understood it. Let $a\in E$. Then there is an open interval $E_a$ such that $\int_a^x f_n^{\prime}(t)dt$ is well-defined for $x\in E_a$. The open interval ensures that $a$ is contained in it, and not some boundary point of the interval.